# Java/MySQL scheduler, reminder for web app and standalone app

Tags: java, mysql, reminders

OK so here is the scenario.

I have a local Java application running on a desktop. Users/clients need to check in to this (by going through required steps) either every day, every other day, weekly, biweekly, monthly, etc (admin-defined for each user).

In my web application, an admin would add the user and the schedule they need to check in to. If the user does not check in by their required time, then the admin would be alerted of this person and he can complete other actions from there.

How should I go about doing this and should it be done through MySQL or Java? I thought about scheduling events in MySQL but that could not be admin-defined on the web app. I'm not sure what else to do for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is good for storing state.  Maintaining records of when they checked in is good, and you can write a script that sees who hasn't checked in when they needed to and alerts the admins.  The Java application then just has to update the MySQL record with the current time everytime they check in.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I researched more into this but I am still new at MySql and am wondering about one more thing. So I see that a script would get the last date logged in for a user, compare it to the current date, and if it longer than say a week, it would alert admins. What would this script be, a stored procedure, function, or how would that work?

Comment: Typically, I write scripts like that in a scripting language, such as PHP.  I think Python is becoming very popular now.  Although I write most of my work in Java, it is overkill for such a simple script.  But that doesn't mean you can't do it.  Using Java, you would create a simple application (command line only would be fine) which does the work that you need and sends out the necessary alert.  Then you schedule it in crontab or windows or wherever to run automatically once a day, hour, whatever you need.